# Is this true for a locally compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a LCH space and $U \subset X$ is open. Does there always exist a compact set $K \subset X$ such that $U\subset K$?

---

I just come up with this question but can either prove it or give an counterexample. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

false, take any non compact but locally compact space $X$, and take $U = X$

Comment: $U\subset X$, not $U\subseteq X$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar. One could take $U=X\setminus\{x\}$ for some $x\in X$. Then $U$ is open by the Hausdorff property, but not compact.